# How to convert a hotspot signal with WPA2 enterprise credentials 802.1x to normal WPA2

Tags: wireless-networking, security, wireless-router, 802.1x, wireless-hotspot

I'm trying to connect an IOT device to the internet using a hotpsot that supports WPA2 enterprise credentials 802.1x type of security. However the IOT device I use can only connect to networks with WPA2 security. What I'am trying to relize is establishing a connection with the hotspot via router/extender or some others ways to prodcast the signal with WPA2 security to connect 1 or multiple devices but in my case is 1 device only. So what can i do to make this happen? a diagram or a recommendation for hardware would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround >>>>> buy a GL-AR300M-EXT and install it as a network repeater, then connect it to the WPA2 Enterprice network. Next, you reconnect your device/devices freely using the WPA2 network that the GL-AR300M-EXT already has build into it.

TIP: Use the LAN port to extend the network radius by adding an access point and you should be good to Go :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your main wireless should remain WPA2 Enterprise.

You also (very most likely) cannot change this router to non-Enterprise.

Add a wireless router that supports WPA2 wireless.

Connect it to the main network LAN to LAN. Give this router a Static IP on the main network. Turn DCHP OFF on the added router. You will need to ensure this router will connect to WPA2 Enterprise.

Now connect your single IOT device to the new router.

That should work fine.

Ultimately, you cannot change the WPA2 Enterprise setup and if an IOT compatible router cannot be added, then you need to find a different and independent approach.

That is, build your own setup for testing your IOT device.

Comment: The hotspot with WPA2 Enterprise is not at home and it's not mine, i have a subscription to be able to use it, so LAN >> LAN is not an option i can only connect to it via Wifi

Comment: Ask who has it to connect a compatible router for you. So far as I know, you cannot remove WPA2 Enterprise if it is not your router.

Comment: They can't do that and they won't remove the WPA2 enterprise because it's obviously implemented for monitoring purposes, otherwise they can't see what each one is doing etc nor keeping a track of all user profiles. There has to be a way to connect to it via router or something and then rebroadcast that signal to normal WPA2

Comment: You need some different way to connect your device. Otherwise the problem is impossible.